# hot water bath to gain muscles

Tags: weight-gain

I have read here hot water helps increase the muscle size.In case we do a hot bath and after we do a workout.First, "hot" how much should it be?Shouldn't my self tolerate it or just relaxing hot?Second, how much time after bath should I do a workout for more gains? Example,I am doing after twenty minutes workout from my bath.I want answer to focused only to hot water not nutritients etc.Thanks

Comment: Where did you hear about this?

Comment: Have you considered the plausibility of hot water increasing muscle size?  By what process(es) could it do so?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think we are aware of any such claims, unless you are talking about expansion of your muscles due to head and making them look bigger, that's an illusion. That's not muscle gain.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment but I am not allowed to comment yet.

I have never heard about hot water being responsible for increased muscle gains. However, taking a hot bath can definitely have positive effects for post-workout muscle relaxation and active recovery.

Taking a cold shower after training, on the other hand, can have slightly positive effects on muscle growth because the cold will increase blood circulation and thus improve nutrient supply to your (muscle) cells. In addition, a cool bath will reduce possible swellings as well as tissue breakdown.